# Scala generic types

Tags: scala, generics

I there, I'm trying to combine the *Command* and *Chain of responsibility* patterns with Scala style.
Basically, I would like to have one `Executor` who pass the command trough the chain and return the result. A *command* is anything that return a `T` :

```
class class Invoker {

  type Command[T] = () => T

  val handlers = new mutable.ListBuffer[PartialFunction[() => T, T]]

  def invoke[T](command: => T): Future[T] = Future {
    handlers.find(_.isDefinedAt(command)).map(_.apply(command))
  }

}
```

But, because I'm a scala beginner, I have problems with the generic types for the list of `handlers`. I cannot figure how to define `T` in the declaration of `handlers` so that the `invoke` command return the correct type (wich should be `T`)

Can someone help me to implement this pattern ?

Comment: " have problems with the generic types for the list of handlers" What problems? Please give details of your issues

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect (`class class`). You need to parameterise the class with type T (`class invoker[T]  {`) and then `invoke` doesn't need a type parameter. Also, command is a call-by-name type, and that's not the same as `()=>T` which is a function of no arg returning T.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to parametrize `Invoker` because it should accept any type of command. So my workaround is to add `.asInstanceOf[T]` on the result of of `handlers... map`. For your second remark about call-by-name. How can I then accept both no arg function and classes who match the `Command` type ?

Comment: A parametized Invoker  would still accept any kind of command that returns T, which is what you said you wanted in the question.  Your handlers ListBuffer only holds one type T (unless you use Any and lose type-safety). It's really not clear what you want -can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: And the result of `handlers.find(_.isDefinedAt(command)).map(_.apply(command))` is an `Option[T]` where you need a `T`. So,  all rather unclear.

Answer (score 2):

There are several sketchy places, but I think the closest you'll get to what you want would be (Though, it will not work, see below):

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Invoker {
  val handlers = new mutable.ListBuffer[PartialFunction[Any, Any]]

  def invoke[T](command: () => T): Future[T] = Future {
    handlers.collectFirst {
      case pf if pf.isDefinedAt(command) => pf(command)
    }.fold(throw new Exception("failure")) {
      _.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }
}
```

However,

1. It will not work because, the partial functions or more specifically pattern matching will most certainly not work as you expect for `Function0`
2. You loose most of your type information through erasure and have to rely upon what you know about the partial functions.
3. In scala, the need to call `asInstanceOf` is a good indicator that something can be done better.

@1
When you define a list of partial functions that match on `Function0` like for example this:

```
val T1: () => Int = () => 1
val T2: () => Int = () => 2
val T3: () => Int = () => 3

val pfs: Seq[PartialFunction[Any, Any]] = Seq(
  PartialFunction[Any, Any] {
    case T1 => T1()
  },
  PartialFunction[Any, Any] {
    case T2 => T2()
  },
  PartialFunction[Any, Any] {
    case T3 => T3()
  }
)
```

Trying to find a match for any function literal will lead to a MatchError:

```
def invoke[T](c: () => T): T = {
  pfs.collectFirst {
    case pf if pf.isDefinedAt(c) => pf(c)
  }.fold(throw new Exception("failure")) {
    _.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}


invoke(() => 1) |-> scala.MatchError: <function0> (of class abc.A$A290$A$A290$$anonfun$ti1$1)
```

This would only work if you define *Constants* for allowed functions and only use those constants, when you call invoke.

You could define them with the `Invoker` object:

```
object Invoker {
  val SomeCommand = () => 5 + 5
  val AnotherCommand = () => 5 * 5

}
```

But that would utterly eliminate any flexibility.

**FINALLY:**

If you want to be able to perform any *Command* then why maintain a list of handlers anyway?

```
object Invoker {
  def invoke[T](command: () => T): Future[T] = Future {
    command()
  }
}
```

should be sufficient for that.